# php type checking for method parameters - is it worth it?

Tags: php, parameters, typechecking

I'm wondering what you think the best practice is here-- does it buy you very much to type-check parameters in PHP? I.e have you actually seen noticeably fewer bugs on projects where you've implemented parameter type-checking vs. those that don't? I'm thinking about stuff like this:

```
public function __construct($screenName, $createdAt) {  
        if (!is_string($screenName) || !is_string($createdAt) {
            return FALSE;
        }
}
```

Comment: If you want typechecking, use a static language.

Comment: I have only used type checking with arrays. Then I stopped re-using variables with different types.

Comment: Ive seen fewer bugs on well planned and written projects. Does this count? ;) By the way: `$createdAt` may also be a timestamp (`int`), or an object (`DateTime`).

Comment: @KingCrunch: I have no clue which PHP version you're using, but from what I know is_string still returns false on integer values and objects.

Comment: @delnan: This question is about PHP if you missed it ;)

Comment: @hakre: Thats what I mean. `string` is the last type I would assume for a parameter named `$createdAt`, but its not accepted here (in fact it is accepted here, because `return false;` within the constructor doesn't have any effect and nothing else happens, if the types doesn't match, but thats just because the example is a kind of incomplete) What I want to say is, that strict typing in this context may cause more confusion, than it may help someone.

Comment: @hakre: Yes, my point exactly. PHP is dynamic, and therefore not suitable if you require a precise type for variables. That's what static typesystems exist for.

Comment: @Delnan: Sure, define the type and type-hint it. Works like a charm.

Comment: @NorthK: You should fix your example code. `return FALSE;` does not work if you want to prevent the object being instantiated. Throw an exception instead. Please update your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normally within a PHP application that makes use of the skalar variable "types" is bound to actually string input (HTTP request). PHP made this easier so to convert string input to numbers so you can use it for calculation and such.

However checking scalar values for [`is_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) as proposed in your example does not make much sense. Because nearly any type of variable in the scalar family is a string or at least can be used as a string. So as for your class example, the question would be, does it actually make sense to check the variable type or not?

For the code you proposed it does not make any sense because you exit the constructor with a `return false;`. This will end the constructor to run and return a not-properly-initialized object.

Instead you should throw an exception, e.g. an `InvalidArgumentException` if a constructors argument does not provide the expected / needed type of value.

Leaving this aside and taking for granted that your object constructor needs to differ between a string and an integer or bool or any other of the scalar types, then you should do the checks.

If you don't rely on the exact scalar types, you can cast to string instead.

Just ensure that the data hidden inside the object is always perfectly all-right and it's not possible that wrong data can slip into private members.

Answer (score 7):

It depends. I'll generally use the [type-hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) that is built into PHP for higher-level objects ((stdClass $obj, array $arr, MyClass $mine)), but when it comes to lower level values -- especially numbers and strings, it becomes a little less beneficial.

For example, if you had the string `'12345'`, that becomes a little difficult to differentiate between that and the number `12345`.

For everything else, the accidental casting of array to a string will be obvious. Class instances which are cast to strings, if they don't have a `__toString`, will make PHP yell. So your only real issue is classes which have a `__toString` method and, well, that really limits the number of times where it can come up. I really wonder if it is worth that level of overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Checking function arguments is a very good practice. I suspect people often don't do that because their functions grow bigger and the code becomes uglier and less readable. Now with PHP 7 you can type-hint scalar types but there is still no solution for cases when you want your parameter to be one of two types: array or instance of \Traversable (which both can be traversed with foreach).

In this case, I recommend having a look at the [args module](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#nsplargs) from [NSPL](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl). The __constructor from your example will have the following look:

```
public function __construct($screenName, $createdAt)
{
    expectsAll(string, [$screenName, $createdAt]);
}

// or require a non-empty array, string or instance of \ArrayAccess
function first($sequence)
{
    expects([nonEmpty, arrayAccess, string], $sequence);
    return $sequence[0];
}
```

More examples [here](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl/blob/master/examples/args.php).

Answer (score 0):

Better documentation is more important when you're the only one interacting with the methods. Standard method definition commenting gives you well documented methods that can easily be compiled into an API that is then used in many IDEs.

When you're exposing your libraries or your inputs to other people, though, it is nice to do type checking and throw errors if your code won't work with their input. Type checking on user input protects you from errors and hacking attempts, and as a library letting other developers know that the input they provided is not what you're expecting is sometimes nice.